# Unable to cast object of type CRM 2013 Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a Synchronous plugin that runs when any opportunity create/delete/update. And in Plugin if any error comes i have made a function which insert log into database.

In table one field if EntityId, so i am writing the following code :

```
foreach (PropertyBagEntry entry in (IEnumerable<PropertyBagEntry>)context.InputParameters.Values)
{

        DynamicEntity entity = (DynamicEntity)entry.Value;
        foreach (Property property in (IEnumerable<Property>)entity.Properties)
        {
            if (property.GetType().Name == "KeyProperty")
            {
                str4 = ((Key)entity.Properties[property.Name]).Value.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

In str4 i am getting EntityId of current process.

But it gives one exception very frequently :

**Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
'ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]'
to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.PropertyBagEntry]'**

And i have identified that the following line is giving error

foreach (PropertyBagEntry entry in (IEnumerable)context.InputParameters.Values)

Anyone have idea to convert this line in another way ?

Comment: This looks to be CRM 4.0 code, since DynamicEntity is a 4.0 SDK entity...

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to get the GUID of current record, if this is the case then you can do it as:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

    try
    {
        if (context.MessageName == "Create" || context.MessageName == "Update")
        {
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && (context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity))
            {
                Entity currentEntity = (Entity) context.InputParameters["Target"];
                Guid currentRecordGuid = currentEntity.Id;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: No, this is not GUID of current record its a proprty ID that i am getting from PropertyBagEntry entry is type of "Dynamic Entity" or "Moniker".

Answer (score 0):

I believe the type of that collection varies from one message to another. If you are looking to get the Id of the record within a plugin, this helper function may come in handy:

```
public static Guid GetEntityIdFromContext(IPluginExecutionContext context)
{
    string messageName = context.MessageName;
    if (context.PrimaryEntityId != Guid.Empty)
    {
        return context.PrimaryEntityId;
    }
    else if (messageName == "Create")
    {
        return new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        return context.PrimaryEntityId;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't help, would you mind providing the message that causes the error?

Comment: e8bba7ae-a552-de11-b475-001e0b4882e2
------------------------------------------------------- 
2b301650-2a38-e411-8cda-005056a07625
 opportunity
   
Plugin 
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 
'ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]' 
to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.PropertyBagEntry]'.

Answer (score 0):

If

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast
>   object of type 'ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.PropertyBagEntry]'

is truly your error, than your issue is not with line

```cs
foreach (Property property in (IEnumerable<Property>)entity.Properties)
```

but with line:

```cs
foreach (PropertyBagEntry entry in (IEnumerable<PropertyBagEntry>)context.InputParameters.Values)
```

The type of context.InputParameters.Values is not castable to an IEnumerable

Comment: @Chirag Don't cast the entire Values property, but enumerate over each value in the InputParameters.Values collection, and then check to see what type it is before casting ( use either the is or as operator).

Comment: Functionally i have understand what you are saying but as i am new in CRM not able to write code to get the same. Would please give code for it.

Comment: @chirag this is not a CRM issue, this is a basic C# issue.  Use the plugin profiler to debug your plugin and see what types are in the input parameters, and how you want to handle them.